# Как сделать, чтобы нельзя выбрать прошедшие даты?

Tags: javascript

пример
сегодня 1 ноября
можно выбрать 2, 3, 4 ноября и тд

но выбрать 31, 30 октября уже нельзя выбрать

```js
$(function() {
  const $datepicker = $('.js-datepicker');
  //var disabledDates = [0, 6];

  let datepicker = $datepicker.datepicker({
    autoClose: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    classes: 'datepicker__calendar',
    position: 'bottom right',
    offset: 22,
    onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
      /*if (cellType == 'day') {
        let day = date.getDay();
        let isDisabled = disabledDates.indexOf(day) != -1;
        return {
          disabled: isDisabled
        }
      }*/
    },
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
      //  if(date) {
      //alert(date);
      //  }
    }
  }).data('datepicker');

});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#de2b2b, #e683cc);
}

.grid {
  padding: 100px 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="grid">

  <div class="datepicker__container">
    <input type='text' class="js-datepicker" id='datepicker' placeholder="Выбрать дату" />
  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Установи параметр `minDate: 0`

```
let datepicker = $datepicker.datepicker({
    ...
    minDate: 0
    ...
});
```

или включая сегодняшний день:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
let datepicker = $datepicker.datepicker({
    ...
    minDate: date
    ...
});
```